# Pressing Enter to Confirm in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I want to make my textbox that when I press enter key it would paste it into the listbox that way won't have the hassle to click the confirm button after inputing something in the textbox.

Comment: Just make the confirm button the `AcceptButton` for the form. Pressing `Enter` will then click that button automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Key_Down event of the Textbox as follows

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, _
                             e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        'Add actions here
    End If
End Sub
```

Or as jmcilhinney commented, simply make the button the Accept Button on the form, that automatically clicks the button when the enter button is pressed.